# How can I split the `ylabel` of a matplotlib figure into rows?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, multiple-columns, axis-labels

How can I split the `ylabel` of a matplotlib figure into rows? I want to keep the `ylabel` on the y-axis rotated. As an example, [here's my subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQJli.jpg) so far, for which the relevant part of the code is below:

```
plt.ylabel('Spacing of Zeroes of $J_{\\nu}(x)$', rotation=0)
```

When I try doing this:

```
plt.ylabel('Spacing of Zeroes of $J_{\\nu}(x)$', rotation=0, ncol=2)
```

I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property ncol
```

Comment: I'm not sure if *columnate* is a word, but if it is, I don't understand it. Also, why would you like to have the ylabel on the x axis?

Comment: By columnate, I mean split the label into two columns, my goal being to fit the ylabel with out leaving lots of white space on the left-side. The ylabel on the x-axis was a typo, I meant y-axis.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you have one column with a string of length N and you divide it into two columns, each with a string of length N/2, the result will be two columns, but the width of the string is still N/2+N/2 = N.

Comment: You're right. I need rows, not columns. Can't believe I missed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestion would be to introduce linebreaks in the string.

```
plt.ylabel('Spacing of\nZeroes of\n$J_{\\nu}(x)$', rotation=0, ha="right")
```

[image]

Comment: That's simple and perfect! Plus I get to pick where it splits. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/multiline.html

```
plt.xlabel('this is a xlabel\n(with newlines!)')
plt.ylabel('this is vertical\ntest', multialignment='center')
```

[image]